# Change rendered HTML in vba WebBrowser control

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control

I have an Access 2010 Form with a WebBrowser control that I would like to remove a Submit button from the rendered HTML. My WebBrowser control works fine when I'm reading the HTML but I get an error when trying to change what's rendered. I've tried several methods and they all return an "Object Required" error. I have a lot of working code that uses the WebBrowser control so I'm hesitant to change it out for another control. Is there anyway of doing this with this control?

Below is a snippet of the latest code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Dim strLook As String
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = WebBrowser1.Document
    Dim txtInner
    strLook = "<input type=""submit"" name=""subaction"" value=""Force"" class=""inputfield"">"
    txtInner = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.innerHTML
    txtInner = Replace(txtInner, strLook, "")
    Webrowser1.Document.Body.innerHTML = txtInner
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim els
    Set doc = WebBrowser1.Document

    Set els = doc.getElementsByTagname("input")
    For Each el In els
        If el.Value = "Force" And el.className = "inputfield" Then
            el.ParentNode.RemoveChild el
            Exit For
        End If
    Next el
End Sub
```